# Futaba GP1006B05 VFD pinout

Tags: dot-matrix-display, vacuum-fluorescent

I have a Futaba GP1006B05 256x64 VFD display.
I need the datasheet, I don't know the pinout. The pin connector is 50 pin.

Does anyone have the GP1006B05 datasheet?

[image: photo of top of VFD PCB]
[image: photo of bottom of VFD PCB]

Answer (score 1):

Futaba doesn't grant open access to product information for some arcane reason, so you have to [register on their site](http://www.futaba.co.jp/en/display/d_dl/index.html) just to search for what is available. You probably have to submit an [inquiry](http://www.futaba.co.jp/en/display/d_inquiry.html) to get the datasheet proper, and I'd bet that you have to do so as a business to get a reply.

Not very good marketing if you ask me, but they don't care.

Reverse engineering doesn't seem plausible either, as a datasheet for the display controller (Futaba 5P00?084-01) isn't available. The [Sony CXK5864BM](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/113557/SONY/CXK5864BM-10L.html) is a 8192 byte (65.6 kbit) SRAM, while the Texas Instruments parts (SN7557XX) are obscure VFD drivers.